# Replace photoswipe share icon by something more obvious

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I'd like to replace the current share icon on [photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com) by a picture of a Facebook like/share button. How could I do that? Is it difficult? (I don't have any knowledge in JS).

Alternatively is it possible to always display the social share floating box?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

[photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com) uses a single image "sprite"-fashion for it's icons, so you would have to edit the file `dist/default-skin/default-skin.png` and replace the section of the graphic that is the share icon.

Unfortunately you can't have the social actions menu always visible - it's behaviour is too embedded and would require some serious hacking.
There is currently an open issue around this - https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/802 - you could add your voice to the issue if it's important to you.